# Angular js/ JavaScript access array element

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I got an json array of `{1:2,2:5,3:5}`. The element before the colon is the id and the value is the element behind the colon. How do I assign the id to variable id and the value to element value.

Answer (score 0):

you mean access to an object , see this : [angular.extend](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/function/angular.extend)

Answer (score 0):

You can use JavaScript's Function like this

```
var Object={1:2,2:5,3:5};

var one=Object.keys(myVar)[0];
var two=Object.keys(myVar)[2];
```

Also In AngularJS you can forEach like this

```
angular.forEach(data, function(value, key) { 
      console.log(Object[key]);          
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use javascript to do it like this,

```
var jsonResp = {1:2,2:5,3:5};
var keys = Object.keys(jsonResp); // Gets all the keys to Keys Array
var values= new Array();
for(var i = 0; i< keys.length; i++){
   values.push(jsonResp[keys[i]]);  // Here get value for each keys
}
console.log(keys);  //Prints ["1", "2", "3"]
console.log(values);  //Prints [2, 5, 5]
```